# I Want To Instatantiate System Workflow Using PlugIn In Online CRM2011

Tags: plugins, workflow-activity, dynamics-crm-online

I have a workflow which need to update a custom entity(say-customentity)
But it will update which record that need to be pass(i.e GUID of that record) using PlugIn.
This PlugIn Fires On Some Event Takes GUID Of That Record And Need To Pass This Guid To System Workflow.I Don't Know How To Pass Parameters To system Workflow.

```
                There Is Some Boundation That Is Why i can not directly trigger that workflow on that event on which PlugIn fires..
```

Any Kind Of Help Will Be Appreciated.

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: I'm sorry Anish but I cannot understand what your question is. Can you please rephrase what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you suggesting a flow of control that goes: WORKFLOW > PLUGIN > WORKFLOW? Are all of these steps operating on the same entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be honest, I only slightly understand your question.

I believe you are asking: "How can I start a workflow programatically? For example in a plugin?".

In which case you do it like this:

```
ExecuteWorkflowRequest request = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest()
{
    WorkflowId = workflowId, //Guid of the workflow you want to start
    EntityId = recordId //Guid of your record
};

ExecuteWorkflowResponse response = (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(request);
```

The workflow must be set to "Run On Demand".

[Full MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309600.aspx)

Comment: So...is this the answer then?